# Asterisk Multicast (SIP)

Tags: asterisk, sip, multicast

How can I setup asterisk to dialog with sip devices using 
the Multicast transmission protocol ?

Basically I have an asterisk box conected to a VSAT network.

On the other end I have a SIP box in a network receiving 
the signal from the other VSAT.

The return from the SIP box to asterisk is unicast.

Is it possible to make it work ?

Comment: This isn't a programming question

Comment: Yes it is. Involves asterisk APIs and it's related configuration files.

Comment: Then rephrase it as a programming question, not as a question of how to configure Asterisk - this isn't an asterisk support forum.

Comment: I don't know why, but all asterisk questions on stackoverflow. On serverfault(where it have be) number of question is much less.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk **SIP** currently not support multicast.

Multicast rtp supported.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+MulticastRTP+channels

Comment: But would it be possible somehow to set this up ? Can I bridge SIP  and MutlicastRTP channels to get it working ?

Comment: No. Sip protocol NOT SUPPORT multicast. Yes, you can bridge any number of channel of any type supported by asterisk inside asterisk.